# VirtualEnv Python as Java PythonInterpreter in MacOS

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm currently finding a way to get some output from a python script through Java. After finding jython, I used `PythonInterpreter` to send parameters and receive output I expect.

**My Code**

```
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    String fileUrlPath = "/Users/me/Desktop/";
    String scriptName = "pythonScript";
    interpreter.exec("import sys\n" + "import os \n" + "sys.path.append('" + fileUrlPath + "')\n"+ "from "+scriptName+" import * \n");
    String funcName = "predictionFunction";
    PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get(funcName);

    try 
    {
        PyObject out = someFunc.__call__(new PyString(pathToImageFolder), new PyString(fileName));
        System.out.println(out);
    } 
    catch (PyException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**My Problem**

But whenever I launch my program, It shows, `numpy module not found` error. So I checked the python version and it showed `2.7.0` which is version of jython python interpreter.

But all my python libraries has been installed in a Virtual environment in path `path/to/vir/env/bin`. So I need to change the interpreter of java `PythonInterpreter` function to the python I've installed in my virtual environment.

is it possible? If so, really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: The only Java `PythonInterpreter` I'm aware of is jython (there is no way to point to cython).

Comment: Jython doesn't support NumPy, or any other C-API extensions. You can use Java array libraries from Jython, but there aren't any that work as a drop-in replacement for NumPy.

Comment: does PythonInterpreter take args?

Comment: @aws_apprentice [`PythonInterpreter`](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html) *is a standard wrapper for a Jython interpreter for embedding in a Java application.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is impossible.

Jython can't use C-API extensions, which includes NumPy. Changing the `sys.path` to include the location where you installed NumPy won't help.

Jython *can* use Java packages, and there are Java packages for array-based numerics, but none of them is anywhere near a drop-in replacement for NumPy; you'd have to rewrite all of your code to use a pretty different API, and it may not have features you're relying on.

---

However, if all you're trying to do is call some Python code with some simple string arguments and get back a string as output, you can do that just by running CPython as a subprocess. And it seems like that's exactly what you're doing: you've got some wrapper code that just imports your module, calls a function with two strings, and prints out the return value as a string.

Step 1: Wrap that Python code up in a script that takes its arguments via `sys.argv`, and outputs its results via `print`.

Step 2: Run your script with the normal CPython interpreter from the virtualenv that has NumPy installed, and capture its output with a pipe.

Step 3: There is no step 3. (Or was it something something life finds a chaos theory because Earth girls are easy? I don't know, it's all Jeff Goldblum.)

Comment: Thank you. I ran CPython as a subprocess and now I receive my output.